# can't install expo with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, expo, npm-install

I have been getting this error when I try to install expo-client. Can anyone help me with that?
[image]

Comment: Are you able to `npm install -g` other packages?

Comment: Apparently, I can't . Still getting the same error